# How to anchor to a navigationController in swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, navigation, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have created a navigationController with an upper button item so I now have a navigation bar at the top of my screen containing a 'logout' button:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))
```

I want to be able to anchor other objects in my code to the bottom of this nav bar. for example, I want to add a search bar thats topAnchor is the bottom on this navigation field that contains my 'logout' button

Answer (score 2):

Cromanelli is correct. You can not anchor to the bottom of an upper UINavigation item. The only fix I found was that the bottom of the upper nav bar is always(regardless of iPhone version) -45 away from the top of the views built-in safe view. One can access this by doing:

item.topAnchor.constraints(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: -45).isActive = true

this will act the same as anchoring an item to the bottom of the upper nav bar.

Answer (score 0):

As per Apple´s documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller UINavigationController is a container view controller that manages one or more child view controllers in a navigation interface. You can't append views at the bottom of the UINavigationBar, what you can do is add the views at the top a UIViewController's view.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correct you need to place a searchBar in the botton of the navigation bar.

**Storyboard**

- Go to your StoryBoard and press `command-shift-L` to open your library.
- Then type searchBar and place it in your ViewController.
- After that you can set constrains to your searchBar.For your
  situation 0 from top so the search pins to the bottom of the
  NavigationBar.

I dont have enough background of what you have already done so i hope that helps.